# oneNote app for windows 10

Tags: printing, microsoft-onenote

when I want to print/send a document to a specific class notebook, it always sends it to the same folder instead of sending the print to the section I have selected. I am note sure why it does it and I have to move the print the print to the correct section afterwards. It's is annoying and a waste of time. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the UWP or Desktop version of OneNote?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly select the Note Book you need to send to in One Note 365 (Desktop).

Make sure you select the correct Print To setting in the Document you are printing.

Make sure the Print Settings are not hidden in Task Bar (the settings were initially hidden for me.

Make sure the One Note Setting "Always send to this note book" is definitely OFF so that One Note will choose.

Whether Desktop or Store One Note, the option to control "Always Save to ..." should be part of the settings. So you would need to examine the One Note Print settings when in that dialogue.

**Note to Readers:**

I started up One Note for Windows 10 on a different machine and the option to Print to One Note for Windows 10 and then Print to a specific Note Book section exists there as well.  So either way, either tool, save to specific Note Book works.

Additional Screen Shot:

[image]

..

[image]

Comment: The author is using the Windows Store version of OneNote. So you might want to make it clear, that version is different from the desktop version, and what you describe is one of those differences.  In other words you should explicitly indicate they must use the Desktop version of OneNote.  This answer is correct, but it would be significantly improved, if you made the point about the differences of the two versions crystal clear.

Comment: One Note store is quite close to One Note desktop, so the Always setting should be there

Comment: The options you describe do not exist on the UWP OneNote.  The options dealing with notebooks are extremely limited in that version.

Comment: Thanks for your input and I did add a clarification.  Microsoft very most likely would allow Print to instead of just Print Anywhere in One Note. That would not fly with users.

Comment: I investiagated and I thought I had answered a question, dealing with exporting of notebooks within OneNote, I discovered the options to export and import only really existed with the Desktop version while the interface (surrounding importing and exporting of notes) for the UWP version was extremely limited.  *I suspect the question was deleted.*  I mention this to illustrate the fact I recently compared to the two versions.